# What is the purpose of the first (1s) element in sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, polynomial

I got confused when I used 10 degrees and got 11 outputs.
I checked the https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html and there seems to be (1) column added to PolynomialFeatures.

For instance, in the example that is provided on that page:

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures 
X = np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2) 
X
array([[0, 1],
   [2, 3],
   [4, 5]])
poly = PolynomialFeatures(2) 
poly.fit_transform(X)
```

Returns

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  9.],
   [ 1.,  4.,  5., 16., 20., 25.]])
```

What is the purpose of "1." elements at the beginning of each list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first term is one of the input column to the power of zero. It works as an intercept in a regression model.

Check this question and answers for details: [When is it ok to remove the intercept in a linear regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-a-linear-regression-model)

Comment: I see, then any regression further has to have fit_intercept=False enabled. If set to True, it returns 0s for intercept.

Comment: Did you already include a column of ones? check also this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779605/in-the-linearregression-method-in-sklearn-what-exactly-is-the-fit-intercept-par

Comment: Yes, after I run PolynomialFeatures(2).fit_transform(x_train) on my train set, and then use Lasso with fit_intercept=False or fit_intercept=True, I get 3 outputs, I get zeros as first element of three in the latter case (set to True):[1.71 1.81 0.61] and  [0.         1.91 0.68]. I'm bootstrapping, so I'm getting many results, but 0s are consistent.

Comment: This is different from the answer in your link. So it's not clear what happens when it's set to True, but I guess it never should be set to True.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know the details behind your comment so I cannot help you on that. It would need another question. There is no need to include another column of ones if you use PolynomialFeatures(), since it already does it.

Comment: Alternatively, set `include_bias=False` in `PolynomialFeatures`. This might be preferable, especially if you want to use a regularized model downstream, so that you don't penalize the intercept term.